# wso2 kubernetes-apim on openshift - what is correct security context?

Tags: kubernetes, wso2, openshift, wso2-api-manager

Deploying WSO2 APIM 2.1.0 on OpenShift using the [published github project](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim), deploying the [pattern-2 use case](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/tree/master/pattern-2/artifacts).

By default the deployed pods have no access to their mapped volumes. As a workaround we set the pods to run under privileged security context, though I'd like to use the default settings.

What is the correct resolution / setup?

I assume I am missing a security context or some mapping to the user uid (set to 1000000000 in the Dockerfile as far I see).

Answer (score 0):

Can you share some details about your environment? Specifically:

1. Is it Openshift running on baremetal, or on a cloud provider like AWS?
2. Are you using NFS for the persistent volumes?

If you have installed your own NFS server in a VM, can you create the same user (wso2user, uid=1000000000 in root group) in the NFS VM, and change the ownership of the shared directories to this user, and try again?

Comment: One environment is at on-premise datacenter, I have my playground on AWS. The NFS is created on a volume claim (with IP address of one of the worker nodes) , that's why I am not sure where I should create the user

Comment: The user should be created in the node that is actually running the NFS. And the permission should be granted to the actual directory that is being shared, in the same NFS node.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue in OpenShift + Azure with AzureDisk. Any solution with default settings?